# How to prevent the suggestedResult from collapsing after clicking result using SearchWidget?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis, esri

How to prevent the suggestedResult from collapsing after clicking result using SearchWidget?

[CodePen](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/?sample=widgets-search-customsource), copied below

```
// An open data address search API for France
const url = "https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/";

const map = new Map({
  basemap: "streets-vector"
});

const view = new MapView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map,
  center: [2.21, 46.22], // lon, lat
  scale: 3000000
});

const customSearchSource = new SearchSource({
  placeholder: "example: 8 Boulevard du Port",
  // Provide a getSuggestions method
  // to provide suggestions to the Search widget
  getSuggestions: (params) => {
    // You can request data from a
    // third-party source to find some
    // suggestions with provided suggestTerm
    // the user types in the Search widget
    return esriRequest(url + "search/", {
      query: {
        q: params.suggestTerm.replace(/ /g, "+"),
        limit: 6,
        lat: view.center.latitude,
        lon: view.center.longitude
      },
      responseType: "json"
    }).then((results) => {
      // Return Suggestion results to display
      // in the Search widget
      return results.data.features.map((feature) => {
        return {
          key: "name",
          text: feature.properties.label,
          sourceIndex: params.sourceIndex
        };
      });
    });
  },
  // Provide a getResults method to find
  // results from the suggestions
  getResults: (params) => {
    // If the Search widget passes the current location,
    // you can use this in your own custom source
    const operation = params.location ? "reverse/" : "search/";
    let query = {};
    // You can perform a different query if a location
    // is provided
    if (params.location) {
      query.lat = params.location.latitude;
      query.lon = params.location.longitude;
    } else {
      query.q = params.suggestResult.text.replace(/ /g, "+");
      query.limit = 6;
    }
    return esriRequest(url + operation, {
      query: query,
      responseType: "json"
    }).then((results) => {
      // Parse the results of your custom search
      const searchResults = results.data.features.map((feature) => {
        // Create a Graphic the Search widget can display
        const graphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: new Point({
            x: feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
            y: feature.geometry.coordinates[1]
          }),
          attributes: feature.properties
        });
        // Optionally, you can provide an extent for
        // a point result, so the view can zoom to it
        const buffer = geometryEngine.geodesicBuffer(
          graphic.geometry,
          100,
          "meters"
        );
        // Return a Search Result
        const searchResult = {
          extent: buffer.extent,
          feature: graphic,
          name: feature.properties.label
        };
        return searchResult;
      });

      // Return an array of Search Results
      return searchResults;
    });
  }
});

// Create Search widget using custom SearchSource
const searchWidget = new Search({
  view: view,
  sources: [customSearchSource],
  includeDefaultSources: false
});

// Add the search widget to the top left corner of the view
view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
  position: "top-right"
});
```

[3d version of code sample above](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-search-3d/)

Comment: Please show `console.log("CanChange: ", response)`

Comment: please check I already post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *documented* way to do this through the API, as far as I can tell. But by adding the `esri-search--show-suggestions` to the SearchWidget, the suggestions will reappear:

```
        const searchWidget = new Search({
          view: view,
          sources: [customSearchSource],
          includeDefaultSources: false,
          //autoSelect: false,
          goToOverride: function(view, { target, options }) {
            view.goTo(target, options);

            const widget = document.querySelector('.esri-search__container')
            widget.className += ' esri-search--show-suggestions'
          },
        });
```

[Working CodePen here](https://codepen.io/codebling/pen/ExwbWjM)

Comment: There are also a few other undocumented ways this can be done